# Excel VBA Refusing to Input/Define a Date in a Cell in the Proper Language

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I gave up on this a long time ago but have decided to hack back into it. I have a program which takes dates from another sheet and reformats them and then inputs them into another sheet containing an invoice. So if I have 21/12/2015, my code should output DECEMBER 21, 2015. The problem is I am using A French computer and it does not paste it in english, which is what I require.

If you want to help me further, I also have to have this program work on a French, American, and Italian computer, I've been looking up ways of temporarily changing the locale of the computer while the workbook is open but no dice. Any ideas?

```
'This is how I used to input the dates, but it only allowed the text to 
'output "DECEMBER-21-2015"

'ActiveCell = _
    "=UPPER(TEXT(Select!I5,""[$-409]MMMM-JJ-AAAA""))&"":"""

'I got my hopes up here, this code works but is the one that is stuck in French

ActiveCell = UCase(Format(SecurityDepositDate, "[-$409]MMMM d, yyyy"))

'This I just tried to see if it would cause any changes

ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "[$-409]MMMM d yyyy;@"
```

Comment: You could create an array of english month names, and format the date "manually"...

Comment: What does `21/12/2015` return in the "French" format? Also, what's the `[-$409]` supposed to do?

Comment: @BruceWayne when 21/12/2015 is written in the cell which is copied. The old code which uses TEXT returned "DECEMBER-21-2015" 

When using the new code where I "got my hopes up" it returns DECEMBRE 21, 2015 (which is in French) 

The purpose of the [-$409] is a locale code, which tells it in which language I want my date to be outputted. You can see in the first instance that it works (without the locale code, it outputs DECEMBRE-21-2015 and for one reason or another, it does not work when applied to my Format code underneath. That's my problem

Comment: @TimWilliams Could you expand on that please? I was thinking of running a macro afterwards that would search for all dates written in French and replace them with english like Novembre = November and so on. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format the date "manually" using an array of month names in whatever language you want:

```
Function TheDate(dt As Date)
    Dim arr
    arr = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", _
               "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
    TheDate = arr(Month(dt) - 1) & " " & Day(dt) & ", " & Year(dt)
End Function
```